# Laravel - How to validate cyrillic

Tags: php, validation, laravel, cyrillic

I need to check if the input is utf-8 cyrillic characters. Is there something like this?

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'name' => 'required|cyrillic'
]);
```

If not how can I achieve that?

Comment: Checking if the input is Cyrillic characters and if the input is UTF-8 Cyrillic characters is two different problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create own custom validation rule:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('cyrillic', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return preg_match('/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u', $value);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to post a link as an answer. Links become outdated and invalidated. It's better if you also extract the relevant parts from the link.

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Comment: What would make this great would be `Validator::extend('cyrillic', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) { return preg_match('/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u', $text); }); instead of the generic `foo` stuff. This would provide a complete answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

```
function isCyrillic($text) {
    return preg_match('/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u', $text);
}
```

will return true if a cyrillic character is encountered

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. This does not answer the Laravel issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using the regex from @Hearner's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483335/1053938), you can add a regular expression to your rules, but when using regular expressions, you should add the rules in an array because the `|` character has special meaning in regular expressions:

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'name' => array('required', 'regex:/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u')
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, laravel 5.2 validation work incorrectly with

> [А-Яа-я]

skipping some symbols like:

> 'У ц ш щ'  , etc.

It's not a brilliant solution, but it's work correctly in my case:

```
 $text_regex = '/^[А-ЯЦцУуШшЩщФфЫыРрЭэЧчТтЬьЮюЪъХхЁа-яёa-zA-Z0-9\- @%;()\$\.\,\"\']+$/';
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'name' => ['required', 'regex:/^[А-Яа-яЁё]$/u'],
]);
```